# How does reactive java access data from couchbase?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm working with spring 5 and reactive programming with couchbase. Can anyone explain in detail how does reactive java pull in data from couchbase? How does couchbase provide reactive support? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Couchbase Java client is implemented with RxJava 1, at least through the 2.x versions.

If you look at, for example, a document `get` operation, you can turn the operation into an observable stream by inserting a call to async. That is, `bucket.async().get(id)` returns a type of `Observable<JsonDocument>`.